# How to customize backgronud and color of tabs?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, react-bootstrap

I'm newbie with **react** and **react-bootstrap** and I would like to **customize background** of a tab when is `active` and **color** of the text of tabs when they are not active. I have tried to overwrite background style `nav-style.active` in an external CSS file but it doesn't work.

How can I customize this attributes and others from **react-bootstrap**?

Comment: Did you use !important to overwrite?

Comment: No, I didn't use !Important. I have used it right now and ... It works!!! Thank you so much @BaranselA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/pz5l469m0?codemirror=1&fontsize=14

Adding a simple CSS will work

```css
.nav-link.active {
    color: red !important;
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```